# How to map a message to a object with `schema` and `payload` in Spark structured streaming correctly?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I am hoping to map a message to a object with `schema` and `payload` inside in during Spark structured streaming.

This is my original code

```
val input_schema = new StructType()
  .add("timestamp", DoubleType)
  .add("current", DoubleType)
  .add("voltage", DoubleType)
  .add("temperature", DoubleType)

val df = spark.readStream
  .schema(input_schema)
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
  .parquet("s3a://my-bucket/my-folder/")
  .select(to_json(struct("*")).alias("value"))

val query = df.writeStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option(
    "kafka.bootstrap.servers",
    "hm-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.hm-kafka.svc:9092"
  )
  .option("topic", "my-topic")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint")
  .start()
```

This will output message in this format when writes to Kafka:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1682556571.14622,
  "current": 2.0172032595808242,
  "voltage": 19.34080877806074,
  "temperature": 37.461518565900434
}
```

However, I hope to add a field `schema` and move this to the `payload` so that later I can sink to Postgres by JDBC Sink Connector such as [Aiven's JDBC Sink and Source Connectors](https://github.com/aiven/jdbc-connector-for-apache-kafka).

Based on [this doc](https://github.com/aiven/jdbc-connector-for-apache-kafka/blob/master/docs/sink-connector.md#data-mapping), I think I should use `"decimal"` as each field type.

So this is the Kafka message format I hope to generate:

```
{
  "schema":{
    "type": "struct",
    "fields":[
      {
        "type": "decimal",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "timestamp"
      },
      {
        "type": "decimal",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "current"
      },
      {
        "type": "decimal",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "voltage"
      },
      {
        "type": "decimal",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "temperature"
      }
    ]
  },
  "payload":{
    "timestamp": 1682556571.14622,
    "current": 2.0172032595808242,
    "voltage": 19.34080877806074,
    "temperature": 37.461518565900434
  }
}
```

I tried to update my Spark code to

```
val input_schema = new StructType()
  .add("timestamp", DoubleType)
  .add("current", DoubleType, nullable = true)
  .add("voltage", DoubleType, nullable = true)
  .add("temperature", DoubleType, nullable = true)

val output_schema = new StructType()
  .add("timestamp", "decimal")
  .add("current", "decimal", nullable = true)
  .add("voltage", "decimal", nullable = true)
  .add("temperature", "decimal", nullable = true)

val df = spark.readStream
  .schema(input_schema)
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
  .parquet("s3a://my-bucket/my-folder/")
  .select(
    to_json(struct("*")).alias("payload")
  )
  .withColumn(
    "schema",
    to_json(struct(
      lit("struct").alias("type"),
      lit(output_schema.fields.map(field => struct(
        lit(field.dataType).alias("type"),
        lit(field.nullable).alias("optional"),
        lit(field.name).alias("field")
      ))).alias("fields")
    ))
  )
  .select(
    to_json(struct(
      col("schema"),
      col("payload")
    )).alias("value")
  )

val query = df.writeStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option(
    "kafka.bootstrap.servers",
    "hm-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.hm-kafka.svc:9092"
  )
  .option("topic", "my-topic")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint")
  .start()
```

But when I `spark-submit`, I got error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkRuntimeException: The feature is not supported: literal for 'DecimalType(10,0)' of class org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.literalTypeUnsupportedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:125)
    at com.hongbomiao.IngestFromS3ToKafka$.$anonfun$main$1(IngestFromS3ToKafka.scala:46)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at com.hongbomiao.IngestFromS3ToKafka$.main(IngestFromS3ToKafka.scala:45)
    at com.hongbomiao.IngestFromS3ToKafka.main(IngestFromS3ToKafka.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1046)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1055)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I kind of feeling `StructType` causing it returns `DecimalType(10,0)`. Maybe in this case I should not use `StructType`?

I am not sure how to generate exactly `"decimal"` in the output message. Any guide would be appreciate, thanks!

Comment: Spark can read and write to JDBC tables. You don't need the schema and payload wrappers unless you have to use Kafka Connect

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer! I do need Kafka this time to avoid blowing up the database as there can be hundreds of millions of data per second during the peak time. The real usage would be another database, but still similar.

Comment: My point was that you don't need Aiven connectors. You can just use Spark for everything, including read/writes to Kafka as well as the [JDBC databases](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my original guess is correct. `StructType` is special and should not be used here. Using `"decimal"` is same with using `DecimalType(10,0)` which is why it shows that error.

- `StructType` [document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html)
- `DecimalType` [document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DecimalType.html)

In my case, I should use simple `struct`.

Also, I found as downstream Aiven's JDBC sink connector [document](https://github.com/aiven/jdbc-connector-for-apache-kafka/blob/2cbe41d90ac4b9ae00c27dcabd7c52de649c3d20/docs/sink-connector.md) may have issue:

[image]

I tried `decimal`, `Decimal`, `DECIMAL`, all failed when running the connector.

As default `value.converter` is `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter`, so I should use `double` (or `float`) in my case based on JsonSchema [source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.4.0/connect/json/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/json/JsonSchema.java#L40-L59).

So the final working version is:

```
val input_schema = new StructType()
  .add("timestamp", DoubleType)
  .add("current", DoubleType, nullable = true)
  .add("voltage", DoubleType, nullable = true)
  .add("temperature", DoubleType, nullable = true)

val df = spark.readStream
  .schema(input_schema)
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
  .parquet("s3a://my-bucket/my-folder/")
  .select(
    struct(
      lit("struct").alias("type"),
      array(
        struct(
          lit("double").alias("type"),
          lit(false).alias("optional"),
          lit("timestamp").alias("field")
        ),
        struct(
          lit("double").alias("type"),
          lit(true).alias("optional"),
          lit("current").alias("field")
        ),
        struct(
          lit("double").alias("type"),
          lit(true).alias("optional"),
          lit("voltage").alias("field")
        ),
        struct(
          lit("double").alias("type"),
          lit(true).alias("optional"),
          lit("temperature").alias("field")
        )
      ).alias("fields")
    ).alias("schema"),
    struct("*").alias("payload")
  )
  .select(to_json(struct("*")).alias("value"))

val query = df.writeStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option(
    "kafka.bootstrap.servers",
    "hm-kafka-kafka-bootstrap.hm-kafka.svc:9092"
  )
  .option("topic", "my-topic")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint")
  .start()
```

This will print format

```
{
  "schema":{
    "type": "struct",
    "fields":[
      {
        "type": "double",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "timestamp"
      },
      {
        "type": "double",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "current"
      },
      {
        "type": "double",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "voltage"
      },
      {
        "type": "double",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "temperature"
      }
    ]
  },
  "payload":{
    "timestamp": 1682556571.14622,
    "current": 2.0172032595808242,
    "voltage": 19.34080877806074,
    "temperature": 37.461518565900434
  }
}
```

Comment: You could just drop the schema object entirely from the record using `get_json_object("$.payload")` function. I see no value in parsing the schema from Spark. Otherwise, by using Avro in Kafka Connect instead, Spark could also infer the schema from a Schema Registry

Comment: Thanks, yeah Avro is my next step 

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer could you clarify `get_json_object("$.payload")`? Sorry, I didn't get it. Thanks!

Comment: It allows you to parse as a string without any schema needed. E.g. `spark.readStream.format("kafka")....select(cast("value").as("string")).select(get_json_object("$.payload"))`. It uses [JSONPath](https://jsonpath.com/) to extract the fields. From there, you can optionally use `select(to_json(col("value"), payloadSchema)` to apply SparkSQL schema... My point was that `"schema"` field in Connect metadata means nothing to SparkSQL, so you should drop it, and skip parsing it

Comment: I see, however, I am reading parquet files as `.parquet("s3a://my-bucket/my-folder/")` shows instead of Kafka. 

Comment: My bad. Same concept applies for any Spark Dataframe with String/JSON data. The alternative solution is to set `value.converter.schemas.enable=false` in your S3 Sink connector